# Avoiding None in f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

If I have an f-string where one of the parameters may be `None`, is there a way to automatically omit it from the string?

`f'{first_name} {prefix} {last_name}'`

If `prefix` is `None` then this string will render as `Arnold None Weber`.

I tried `f'{first_name} {prefix or ''} {last_name}'` but that's a syntax error.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> I tried f'{first_name} {prefix or ''} {last_name}' but that's a syntax error.

The only reason it's a syntax error is that you tried to put single quotes inside single quotes. All of the usual ways of fixing it will work:

```
f'{first_name} {prefix or ""} {last_name}'
f"{first_name} {prefix or ''} {last_name}"
f"""{first_name} {prefix or ''} {last_name}"""
```

However, notice that this doesn't quite do what you want. You won't get `Arnold Weber`, but `Arnold  Weber`, because the spaces on either end aren't conditional. You could do something like this:

```
f'{first_name} {prefix+" " if prefix else ""}{last_name}'
f'{first_name} {prefix or ""}{" " if prefix else ""}{last_name}'
```

… but at that point, I don't think you're getting the conciseness and readability benefits of f-strings anymore. Maybe consider something different, like:

```
' '.join(part for part in (first_name, prefix, last_name) if part)
' '.join(filter(None, (first_name, prefix, last_name)))
```

Not that this is *shorter*—but the logic is a lot clearer.

Comment: The one with the backslashes doesn't work - backslashes aren't allowed in the expression, unless they changed it in 3.7.

Comment: I prefer the last option `' '.join(filter(None, (first_name, prefix, last_name)))`

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's a syntax error; you broke your string.

```
f'{first_name} {prefix or ""} {last_name}'
```